# log4j2 logger.entry() method not printing the log message

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 framework,in every method I am trying to log entry and exit by calling entry() at the start and exit() at the end but those methods are not printing any log information.Please any one can help me out as I am new to this framework.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console target="SYSTEM_OUT" name="CONSOLE">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
    <Root level="ERROR">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Show your logging configuration - do you have the relevant loggers and appenders configured to show TRACE-level messages?

Comment: Hi Roberts,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
<Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
</Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Root level="error">
<AppenderRef ref="Console" />
</Root>
<Root level="TRACE">
<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Root>
<Root level="ERROR">
<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Root>
<Root level="info">
<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Root>
        
<Root level="debug">
<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Root>       
     </Loggers>
 </Configuration>

Comment: Could you edit that into the question? Use the `{}` button to indent it by four spaces to preserve the formatting. On SO you can always edit your own posts, and as you gain reputation points you'll be able to edit other people's too.

Comment: Hi roberts,Thanks for your inputs.I edited the question.Please help me out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the previous answer: your config can only have *one* `<Root>` element.

Then, to answer your question about the entry() and exit() methods, for those to be useful you need to enable *location* information in your pattern. For example:

`<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %method - %msg%n" />`

Comment: Thank you very much roberts and Pompa for your valuble inputs

Comment: Were you able to see entry() and exit() information in the log files after adding location information to your pattern config?

Comment: Yes Pompa .I am able to see location info of methods entry and exit after adding pattern given by you.Is there any way to log info of entering and exiting loops also.

Comment: You can manually put entry() at the beginning and exit() at the end of each method but these methods were designed so that a bytecode manipulation tool could insert them automatically. If you want to log a message you are probably better off using the trace(), debug(), info(), warn() and error() methods. (Location will work for these methods also.)

Answer (score 2):

There should only be one `Root` definition in the configuration file - the level you set for a logger is the *finest* detail level that that logger will produce, so a logger set to TRACE will produce TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL messages, one set to ERROR will produce only ERROR and FATAL messages, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console target="SYSTEM_OUT" name="CONSOLE">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This configuration would log *all* log messages at all levels from any logger (in your own or in third-party code) to the console.  More common would be to set things up so that most loggers use a higher threshold but you can turn on more detailed logging for the classes that specifically require it, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console target="SYSTEM_OUT" name="CONSOLE">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <!-- log TRACE-level messages for com.example and its descendants -->
    <Logger level="trace" name="com.example" />
    <!-- but only WARN or higher for anything else -->
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```